# Discord.Js Message Link

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I've looked through the `discord.js` docs. I'm not too good at reading docs but is there a way to get the url of the message that initiated the command like:

```js
console.log(`${message.content.URL}`)
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the URL of a message, you can just use [`.url`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=url). The code would look something like:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    const url = message.url
})
```

Comment: Im not allowed to upvote things yet but thanks this worked

Comment: You can just accept the answer because you wrote the question